# C# XML Databinding Winforms

Tags: c#, xml, data-binding

let me describe the situation. Winforms C#
I have xml file with data. I load this data to an user defined class object using `Deserialize`.
Based on this object with data, I build [in Form] UI: many `tabPages` of custom controls (textBox, 2 buttons in groupBox). I can also save this user defined class object using `Serialize` to XML file. 

**Question:**

user class:

```
public class Layout
{
    public string type;
    public List<TabPage> TabPageList;

    public Layout()
    {
        this.TabPageList = new List<TabPage>();
    }
}
public class TabPage
{
    public string text;
    public List<ActionGroup> ActionGroupList;

    public TabPage()
    {
        this.ActionGroupList = new List<ActionGroup>();
    }
}
public class ActionGroup
{
    public string type;
    public string text;
    string sourceLocal;
    string sourceRemote;

    public ActionGroup()
    {
        this.type = string.Empty;
        this.text = string.Empty;
        this.SourceLocal = string.Empty;
        this.SourceRemote = string.Empty;
    }

    public string SourceLocal
    {
        get { return sourceLocal; }
        set { sourceLocal = value; }
    }
    public string SourceRemote
    {
        get { return sourceRemote; }
        set { sourceRemote = value; }
    }
}
```

Custom control:

```
public partial class ViewActionGroup : UserControl
{
    public string type;
    public string text;
    string sourceLocal;
    string sourceRemote;
    public bool isRemote;
    public bool isDone;

    public ViewActionGroup()
    {
        this.type = string.Empty;
        this.text = string.Empty;
        this.SourceLocal = string.Empty;
        this.SourceRemote = string.Empty;
        this.isRemote = false;
        this.isDone = false;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public ViewActionGroup(ActionGroup actionGroup)
    {
        this.type = actionGroup.type;
        this.text = actionGroup.text;
        this.SourceLocal = actionGroup.SourceLocal;
        this.SourceRemote = actionGroup.SourceRemote;
        this.isRemote = false;
        this.isDone = false;
        InitializeComponent();

        groupBox1.Text = text;
        button1.Text = type;
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
        textBox1.Text = SourceLocal;
        textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
    }

    public string SourceLocal
    {
        get { return sourceLocal; }
        set { sourceLocal = value; }
    }
    public string SourceRemote
    {
        get { return sourceRemote; }
        set { sourceRemote = value; }
    }

    public void ChangeToRemote()
    {
        this.SourceLocal = textBox1.Text;
        isRemote = true;
        textBox1.Text = this.SourceRemote;            
    }

    public void ChangeToLocal()
    {
        this.SourceRemote = textBox1.Text;
        isRemote = false;
        textBox1.Text = this.SourceLocal;            
    }
}
```

Creating UI with connection between UI and data object:

```
private void CreateLayout(Layout layout)
    {
        this.Text = layout.type;
        if (panelMain.Controls.Count>0)
        {
            panelMain.Controls.Clear();
        }
        TabControl tabControl = new TabControl();

        tabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        int tabCount = 0;

        foreach (TabPage tabpage in layout.TabPageList)
        {
            int actionCount = 0;

            tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabpage.text);
            foreach (ActionGroup actionGroup in tabpage.ActionGroupList)
            {
                ViewActionGroup view = new ViewActionGroup(actionGroup);
                view.Location = new Point(0, actionCount * view.Height);
                view.DataBindings.Add("SourceLocal", actionGroup, "SourceLocal", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
                view.DataBindings.Add("SourceRemote", actionGroup, "SourceRemote", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
                tabControl.TabPages[tabCount].Controls.Add(view);
                tabControl.TabPages[tabCount].AutoScroll = true;
                tabControl.TabPages[tabCount].AutoScrollMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(tabControl.Width/2,tabControl.Height);
                actionCount++;
            }
            tabCount++;
            this.panelMain.Controls.Add(tabControl);
        }

    }
```

The problem I get happens here:

```
view.DataBindings.Add("SourceLocal", actionGroup, "SourceLocal", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
view.DataBindings.Add("SourceRemote", actionGroup, "SourceRemote", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

I can bind only one property. The first one works. The second does not work properly. When saving back to xml file I get only local source update.
When I commented LocalSource binding then it works for RemoteSource. I guess I pass those bindings wrong to control. But how to do it properly?

Solution would be to have on-to-one connection of LocalSource/RemoteSource in Custom Control and CustomClass object.

Comment: When and how are ChangeToRemote/ChangeToLocal called? And have you checked that they are called? What does textBox1_TextChanged do?

Comment: @Ralf ChangeToRemote/Local is done by checkbox.Checked in main form. It is called for sure. Data is updated in controls but not binded correctly to layout object. textBox1_TextChanged is empty (commented out inside, was used before trial with dataBinding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to enclose this two or more properties in one object.

additional class:

```
public class Source
{
    string sourceLocal;
    string sourceRemote;

    public Source()
    {
        sourceLocal = string.Empty;
        sourceRemote = string.Empty;
    }

    public string SourceLocal
    {
        get { return sourceLocal; }
        set { sourceLocal = value; }
    }

    public string SourceRemote
    {
        get { return sourceRemote; }
        set { sourceRemote = value; }
    }

    public Source(string local,string remote)
    {
        SourceLocal = local;
        SourceRemote = remote;
    }


}
```

Then in previous classes:

```
public class ActionGroup
{
    public string type;
    public string text;
    Source source;

    public ActionGroup()
    {
        this.type = string.Empty;
        this.text = string.Empty;
        this.source = new Source();
    }

    public Source Source
    {
        get { return source; }
        set { source = value; }
    }
}
```

And finally binding:

```
view.DataBindings.Add("Source", actionGroup, "Source", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```